# how to restrict all pages of website to be opened once on complete computer. explanation provided

Tags: c#, iis, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i restrict the part of a website so that it can be viewed by only one computer at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080711/how-can-i-restrict-the-part-of-a-website-so-that-it-can-be-viewed-by-only-one-com)

i want to implement a restriction such that only one copy of a page can be opened at a time.

that is example:-
open firefox type stackoverflow.com 
--new tab--again stackoverflow.com 
---new tab--again stackoverflow.com 
----new tab--again stackoverflow.com 
-----new tab--again stackoverflow.com 
-------new tab--again stackoverflow.com

THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN, IF one tab has websiteQ/home opened, another tab should be displaying you already have this page opened!
but if another tab tries to open websiteQ/part1 that should work, but if another tab tries to open websiteQ/part1 error should be displayed.

by complete computer i mean

the above  restriction should remain valid across all browsers,

that is

if firefox has websiteQ/alpha opened and iexplorer tries to open websiteQ/alpha then it should display page already opened.

i read somewhere that declaring anything static cause it to not have instances created, so shall i make all classes static!?

again:-
theres a dbserver with sql server 2005 express, a webserver with iis5, and three clients

c# asp.net vs 08